# No cold air - AC Compressor clutch engage with LP side 0 psi

Tags: ac

No cold air
AC Compressor clutch is engaged
Low pressure is "0"
tried to add Freon and immediately jumps to 150 psi
relieve pressure and again immediately back to 0 with clutch still engaged
never seen this before - how can the clutch be engaged with no pressure on LP side?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the system is plugged. You never state what your high side reading is ... more than likely it would scare you if you did see it. If it's plugged and you still have pressure on the high side, I can see that it *might* engage that way. It definitely wouldn't be good to run it too long that way. You also wouldn't see anything in the way of cooling going on, either. You don't mention anything about the vehicle in question, so can speculate no further on where that plug might be or what's going on beyond that.

Comment: High side 180 psi - and I have let the system run for the past hour and the lp side is now up to 30 psi.

Comment: 2009 Honda odyssey

Comment: I agree with your opinion - I can repair most issues but will pass on this one and will take to a professional thank you